# Change timezone of date before sending to MonngoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, date, timezone, mongodb-query

I am querying mongo db with below query

```
 Query: { "modifiedDate" : { "$lt" : { "$date" : "2016-01-20T05:08:28.000Z"}}
```

This date in `modifiedDate` is provided to backend by UI in long format which has value `1453286308000.`
This long date is converted into Date Object using below line

```
DateTime(value).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZoneId)).toDate()
```

Returned is Date class object of value `"2016-01-20 10:38:28"`. I want this date in UTC format before querying into mongoDB.
Mongo query,

```
Criteria.where(MODIFIED_DATE).lt(date)
```

Date Object which is coming in query is `"2016-01-20T05:08:28."` not `"2016-01-20 10:38:28"` which is expected.

This `5.30` hrs difference is caused because date is considering local timezone. Is it possible to avoid it.

I tried using

```
 Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
 cal.setTimeInMillis(value + TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset());
```

which gives me the expected result. But Is there a better approach or will it work in all scenarios?